# Missing .dll files in an executable kivy application (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I created a kivy application that allows plotting some graphics by using matplotlib lib. it worked well, and than i converted it to .exe with cx_freeze, it displayed this error :

> Intel MKL FATAL ERROR : Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.

After hours in forums, i putted all the mkl .dll files that exists in the *Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\\Library\bin* **in** *Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core* folder because matplotlib needs numpy. with this action, the executable works perfectly on my laptop but not for the other users's laptops, it displayed this error :

> System Error
>
> The program can't start because mkl_core.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the
> program to fix this problem.

And then i putted the dll files in some folders in the executable's lib folder and now it displays this error :

> System Error
>
> The program can't start because libiomp5md.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the
> program to fix this problem

I don't understand whey these errors and how to solve this issue. I know that there is no error in my scripts (myapp.py and setup.py ) because it works well in my laptop.

Have you any idea please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you properly assigned access permissions to the files. If you put them manually they may get your user's permissions and hence appear to be missing (inaccessible) for any other user.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but i don't think it's a permissions issue, because i already delivered some kivy applications which works fine for them. (it's the same process). In this app, this errors are caused by matplotlib

Comment: There may be issues with %PATH% setup that does not lead to the directories where you have the DLLs in question and the binary dependency of the script is not satisfied. Also, it is not clear to me from the question if you added all of the transitive dependencies to your installation package (you have to do it explicitly).

Comment: Finally it worked, i putted the mkl .dll and .dll files that start with 'lib' that exist in Library/bin folder in the same location as the executable. thank you for your suggestion , it helped me.